# Horizontal Scroll View for drawing graph

Tags: android

I am creating a graph by the values taken from database.So my values can change everytime.
It is not being fitted on screen , its going out of screen.
Can you please tell me how to create horizontal scroll view for this.

Answer (score 0):

All these  TextView and Buttons are under Single Horizontal Scroll View..try this way..

```
<HorizontalScrollView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             <TextView
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Inside 1st HorizontalScrollView" />
             <Button
               android:text="Button A1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
             <Button
               android:text="Button A2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
         </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```